# Filter implode title and separator string wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, filter

I would like to replace part of this string:

```
$title = implode( " $sep ", array_filter( $title ) );
```

Full function here:

```
function wp_get_document_title() {
$title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
    return $title;
}

global $page, $paged;

$title = array(
    'title' => '',
);

if ( is_404() ) {
    $title['title'] = __( 'Page not found' );
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
    $title['title'] = sprintf( __( 'Search Results for &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), get_search_query() );
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    $title['title'] = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
} elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $title['title'] = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_tax() ) {
    $title['title'] = single_term_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_home() || is_singular() ) {
    $title['title'] = single_post_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
    $title['title'] = single_term_title( '', false );
} elseif ( is_author() && $author = get_queried_object() ) {
    $title['title'] = $author->display_name;
} elseif ( is_year() ) {
    $title['title'] = get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format' ) );
} elseif ( is_month() ) {
    $title['title'] = get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format' ) );

} elseif ( is_day() ) {
    $title['title'] = get_the_date();
}

if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
    $title['page'] = sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
}

if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $title['tagline'] = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
} else {
    $title['site'] = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
}

$sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '-' );

$title = apply_filters( 'document_title_parts', $title );

$title = implode( " $sep ", array_filter( $title ) );
$title = wptexturize( $title );
$title = convert_chars( $title );
$title = esc_html( $title );
$title = capital_P_dangit( $title );

return $title;
}

function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```

However, this is under the `wp-includes/general-template.php` and I would like to filter this through my `functions.php` so as not to affect the core file.

Is there a way I could filter out the spaces before and after the `$sep` function? Essentially I want the Title to change for SEO reasons and only want the separator gone on the front page.. something along these lines (this does not work of course):

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { 
    $title = implode( "", array_filter( $title ) ); 
} else { 
    $title = implode( " $sep ", array_filter( $title ) ); 
} ?>
```

Is there a way to filter that or use `str_replace`?

Comment: `$sep` is undefined in there, so whever you're trying to do with that will NOT work.

Comment: There MAY be an answer (it's a bit of a hack), but to give you a good answer this question is missing a critical part: Where is this getting called? Do you have access to the full string AFTER it's called?

Comment: @cale_b thanks, I added the full function in there

Comment: In your `is_front_page()...` code above, you're passing in $sep - where is that defined?

Comment: @cale_b `$sep` is defined in `function wp_get_document_title()` a few lines above the string I would like to modify

Comment: I understand that, but you have a snippet where you claim to be using the title at the end of your question.  In that snippet, you are using `$sep`.  Is this your actual code? I don't think this is how you're using this at the moment....

Comment: Oh, no that is what I was thinking would be a pathway  to get to what I want to do, but I understand that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `document_title_separator` filter and `pre_get_document_title` in WordPress 4.4+.

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/

Setting the separator to something like `$%` then using it in conjunction with a `preg_replace`. You can then match the pattern with the added white spaces for example `'/ \$% /'` against the whole title.

In `functions.php`:

```
<?php

if ( is_front_page() ) {
    add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'theme_mod_title');
}

function theme_mod_title() {

    add_filter('document_title_separator', function() {
        return '$%';
    });

    remove_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'theme_mod_title');

    $pattern = '/ \$% /';
    $desired = '-';
    $title = wp_get_document_title();

    return preg_replace($pattern, $desired, $title);
}
```

Comment: Won't do it because $title = implode( " $sep ", array_filter( $title ) );  comes after the document_title_separator

Comment: @Kevin I am abstaining form modifying the general-template.php as it is a core file which is why I would like to filter through functions.php

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that worked out perfectly in conjunction with the `if ( is_front_page() ) { }` call